# Using subfiles package for beamer documents

Tags: beamer, subfiles

When using `subfiles` package for beamer documents, I got wrong header bars in frames of sub files. My main file is as follows:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{sub}
\end{document}
```

And the sub file is as follows:

```
% sub.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
Hello World!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result of `sub.pdf` is wrong. What's the problem with `subfiles` package?

[image]

Comment: I am still looking for a solution of this problem. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `subfiles` (which I think uses `standalone`) you can directly use `standalone` and its support to `beamer` presentations. Try with:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}% <--------
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\input{sub}%<---- input not include
\end{document}
```

and

```
% sub.tex
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}%<-- standalone instead of subfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%<---- (or standaloneframe, I'm not sure)
\frametitle{Hello}
Hello World!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, `subfiles` doesn't use `standalone`. I'm curious about why `subfiles` doesn't work with `beamer`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because beamer modifies `\document`, but `subfiles` restores it.  If  `\document` were saved *after* the class is loaded, then the problem would disappear.  I suggest replacing `subfiles.cls` with:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{subfiles}[2012/05/23 Federico Garcia]
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\DeclareOption*{\typeout{Preamble taken from file `\CurrentOption'}%
  \let\preamble@file\CurrentOption}
\ProcessOptions

\newcommand{\documentclass@subfiles}[2][]{%
  \global\let\@classoptionslist\relax
  \LoadClass[#1]{#2}
  \global\let\old@document@subfiles\document
  \global\let\old@enddocument@subfiles\enddocument
  \global\let\document\comment
  \global\let\enddocument\endcomment
}
\let\old@documentclass@subfiles\documentclass
\let\documentclass\documentclass@subfiles

\input{\preamble@file}

{\catcode`\@=11
  \global\let\document\old@document@subfiles
  \global\let\enddocument\old@enddocument@subfiles
  \global\let\documentclass\old@documentclass@subfiles
  \global\let\old@document@subfiles\undefined
  \global\let\old@enddocument@subfiles\undefined
  \global\let\old@documentclass@subfiles\undefined}
\endinput
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

If you just want to include some files containing frames, do as follows :

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} % Nice theme
\begin{document}
\input{sub}
\end{document}
```

and the sub file :

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
Hello World!
\end{frame}
```

You can then create many files as you want as inputs, but never use `documentclass`, nor `begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`

Comment: In fact, `subfiles` package make both `main.tex` and `sub.tex` be compiled standalone without error.