# subfiles not detecting draft mode

Tags: margins, conditionals, draft, subfiles

> *specs*: win7x64, miktex, texstudio
>
> *folder structure*:
>
> ```
> root/
>  - main.tex
>  - text.tex
> ```

I get expected wider left margin in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext} % accessories
\usepackage{showframe} % accessories

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
    \ifdraft{\geometry{left=6cm, right=1cm, vmargin={2.5cm,3cm}, marginparwidth=5.5cm}}
            {\geometry{left=2.7cm, right=2.7cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.7cm}}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
    \blindtext
\subfile{text}    
\end{document}
```

[image: output_mwe]

However, when I compile `text.tex` on its own, it does not pick the draft mode:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: output_mwe-alt]

The left margin is just the normal width.

**QUESTION** Any ideas on how I can keep this conditional layout for single chapters?

I also use the `\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes}`, to have notes in that left margin which will disappear under the `final` mode.

Comment: subfiles is a bit "hacky", importing the main file while redefining its document environment as "comment" ... have you tested whether it accepts optional arguments of article at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, it accepts only one option, i.e. the main file reference.

Comment: By the way, somebody should tell the writer of `subfiles` (Federico Garcia) about that bug. @Oleg, do you want to write a short e-mail?

Comment: @Ruben I already tried before posting but no answer so far. If only latex packages could be improved collaboratively...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add

```
\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{draft}
\makeatother
```

before the `\documentclass` line (while canceling out the explicit 'draft' option from your class declaration) in the `main.tex` to make sure that the draft option is active also in your subfile `text.tex`. The following one-liner is equivalent:

```
\bgroup\makeatletter\gdef\@classoptionslist{draft}\egroup
```

Obviously, once you want to change to 'final' just delete or comment out that line.

[image: demo-pic]

---

#### Alternative

You can also specify the 'draft' option directly in your subfile:

```
\documentclass[draft,main.tex]{subfiles}
```

It will be discarded anyway when the subfile gets included back to `main.tex` (see `\skip@preamble` in `subfiles.sty`).

**Important**: Make sure that the parent file name is the last option as `subfiles.cls` lets the internal macro that saves the parents file name, i.e. `\preamble@file`, to the `\CurrentOption` inside a starred option declaration.

<sub>*Tested with version 1.1 of `subfiles` from 2012/05/23.*</sub>

Comment: I would write in bold the `Important(!)`. Otherwise, really concise/elegant and complete. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @OlegKomarov! And I'll change it to bold, it's better ;)

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative would be to modify `subfiles.cls` to *reset* `\@classoptionslist` before calling `LoadClass`.  Indeed, `LoadClass` checks that this variable is empty before setting it to the list of options.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429679/65) for a candidate implementation.